# Failed to validate credentials with APNS. Error is A call to SSPI failed

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I Tried to upload APNS certificate to azure but i got this error

```
        {
            "error": {
                "message": "SubCode=40000. Failed to validate credentials with APNS.A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception...TrackingId:d6013a4a-53d2-495d-96aa-7250c7a67cbb_M5CH3_M5CH3_G3,TimeStamp: 9/30/2018 2: 34: 46 PM",
                "code": "BadRequest"
            }
        }
```

any help ?

Comment: I assume this is from your powershell. If yes then you can get the detailed log using your trackinngId
`Get-AzureRMLog -CorrelationId xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -DetailedOutput`

Comment: @Jayendran I didn't understand sorry can you clarify?

Comment: This is the topmost error description, you can get the detailed exception to get more insights on this issue by using the Tracking ID.

Comment: well , how to get the error description ? i have the tracking id where i should type the command you entered ?

Comment: From your powershell